# `cmd` after creating `.bowerrc` how to add directory path

Tags: windows, bower

I am using `cmd` command to create `.bowerrc` file. but i try to add the `directory path` in to created file like this:

```
D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>touch .bowerrc

D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>{"directory":"public/lib"}
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>.bowerrc {"directory":"public/lib"}

D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>

D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>edit .bowerrc
'edit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>
```

But all this fails.. what is the correct way to add the `directory` object in the file?

I am using `windows7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
echo {"directory":"public/lib"} > .bowerrc
```

Comment: Where can i get all the command a `js` app developer requires?

Comment: I'm not really sure there is such list. For a list of Windows command prompt options simply type help in the command prompt